# Fail using OTA - Network ports

Tags: esp8266

I was using OTA to upload sketches to ESP ports I have ( around 10 ESPs).
For some time now - I'm having some kind of a trouble I would like to share, since I've read some similar topics, but all didn't work.

The problem is when trying to select `Network Port` as I did before, sometimes I see all, sometimes part, sometimes only one or two, and sometimes after selecting to one I want to upload to, it fails since it disapears from that list by the time it starts the upload.

I'm using IDE 1.8.8 on a Linux machine - same issue,

Tried on mac, using both 1.8.8 and even downgraded to 1.8.7 - and I'm getting the same issue.

What might be the cause for that ?

Comment: it could be the wifi AP or router - my wifi router for example does not handle ESP8266's very well at all (WRT32X) - it's a known issue with this router. One way to fix it on the WRT32X is to turn off `WMM`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a Xiami R3 router. Do you know if it applies as well ? what is WMM ?

Comment: no idea, I just presented a similar issue ... WMM is wifi multimedia mode or something like that

Comment: nevermind, I thought the latest dev version of arduino/esp8266 fixed this issue - but OTA still fails most of the time

Comment: @JaromandaX as a workaround ( mostly works, but still..) after a reset command ( which is an MQTT predefined command), the particular device pops back into that list.